# Download all pictures from a whole website

Tags: windows, images, firefox, download-manager

I'm talking about 1000 pictures, the format being something like (not the real site!) travelpics.com/page1-index.html then same thing and page2, 3, 100, etc.

I am using Firefox and I have imagehostgrabber which is even useless for the one page because this person uses different hosts, like imagebox, which for some reason isn't downloaded by my FF extension. I used to have downthemall which I think does also download imagebox.

But that's beside the point. Just saying it takes forever to individually click these pictures.

I heard of hTTrack but also heard it's very slow and also saves the whole website together, not pictures separately.

Comment: Read up on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602153/how-do-i-use-wget-to-download-all-images-into-a-single-folder

Comment: You might have noticed you're getting just more-or-less "1-liners with a link" as answers. This is most likely due to how your question is phrased. Could you please [edit] it and make your requirements more obvious, e.g. using bullet points, explaining (or linking to) what "imagebox" is supposed to mean, name your price limit, etc? For a guide, see: [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Thanks in advance!

Comment: The format of the pictures is not `travelpics.com/page1-index.html`. Please [edit] and say what kind if pictures.

Answer (score 2):

Use [WinHTTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/) together with a file management tool like [Total Commander](https://www.ghisler.com/).

- Who cares if its slow? It's way faster than what you're doing now. Let it run overnight.
- Who cares if the rest of the website is written to your disk as well? You can select the image files from that download. Note that the software has to download the html files *anyway* in order to parse them and follow the links to the images. Also, the bulk of the download *size* will be the images, not the html pages.

With WinHTTrack, specify that it *should* follow links to other websites (+ whatever settings you like).
After the website is downloaded all files will be in one directory tree. Search for *.jpg (or any other naming format) files with Total Commander (default all levels), choose *Feed to listbox*, then select all the files in that pane, and move them to a destination folder of choice.

Then remove the (rest of the) downloaded directory.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into an addon that will allow you to infinitely scroll through numbered pages like [autopager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/autopager/) and pair it with an auto image downloader like you have used.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Snagit, there was a feature just like that in Snagit 10, I don't see why it wouldn't be in the current [Snagit 12](https://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html). It has a 15-day trial if you only need it for a short while.

Answer (score 0):

I have always used the Grabber option in IDM to download all the files from a webpage. It's quick and you can define how many levels deep you want it to search: https://www.premiuminfo.org/download-multiple-files-with-idm-using-grabber/

If you are looking for a free version, you might look at some of the options in this link below. I haven't tried them so can't comment on their functionality.
https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-download-all-files-from-a-folder-on-a-website-or-ftp/